# select from table using sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table

```
   id | name       | type          |    x          | y           | z                | refer
 -----+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------
 1001 | A          |          4    |               |             |                  |           0
 2000 | B          |          2    |   -1062731776 |             |           -65536 |        1001
 2001 | C          |          2    |     167772160 |             |        -16777216 |        1001
 2002 | D          |          2    |   -1408237568 |             |         -1048576 |        1001
```

I need to select columns name,x,y,z if in refer column it refers to id column
and name must be of that id's name. Is it possible with a single query? can anyone please help
here, output should be:

```
name| x               |     y       | z
----+-----------------+-------------+-----------------
 A  |   -1062731776   |             |           -65536
 A  |     167772160   |             |        -16777216 
 A  |   -1408237568   |             |         -1048576
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.x, t2.y, t2.z FROM TABLENAME t1
JOIN TABLENAME t2 on t1.id = t2.refer
```